# Error 405 with Propfind on IIS7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, webdav

I'm attempting to get SCCM running and one of the problems I'm running into is that WebDAV is not functioning properly on the server.  After a lot of tracing, I've figured out that the problem is that IIS7 is giving a status 405 whenever the PROPFIND command is issued.  However, its giving status 200 whenever OPTIONS is issued, and "Allow Anonymous Property Queries" is set to true.  Further, I've also set the host header.

Anyone have any insight into this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up having to reinstall SCCM and rebuild everything from scratch.